# Titanium Mobile: Cannot build android modules in 3.3.0

Tags: android, ant, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

Update:  To clarify, I can build the process successfully.  The question is about installing the example project directly on a device (though I'm thinking emulator won't work either).

I developed a module about two years ago that allowed bluetooth connectivity on Android.  I believe the latest version of the Titanium SDK at the time was around 2.0.  I believe the specifics of the module and the example app are irrelevant to this question.  I will ask my question first, and then try and explain the steps that I have gone through to lead me to the actual question.

My question is: is something in my environment misconfigured, or is this a bug in the Titanium SDK?

If it is the latter, I am very surprised that I can't find any information about it, since it prevents android modules from installing with ant in the latest SDK.

Information about my build environment:

- Mac OS 10.9.5
- Titanium Studio 3.3.0.GA
- Ti CLI 3.3.0
- Android 19
- `java -version`: java version "1.6.0_65"
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)

I am trying to build it now for the latest SDK, 3.3.0 at the time of this writing.  I found that when I tried to build (install) with ant, it resulted in the following output:

```
[exec] [ERROR] /var/folders/x7/h7lgzf1n4nx7fcwr26fdrzxr0000gn/T/mTUYC62ti/testmodule/build/android/res/values-v14/themes_base.xml:133: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionBarWidgetTheme'.
[exec] [ERROR] /var/folders/x7/h7lgzf1n4nx7fcwr26fdrzxr0000gn/T/mTUYC62ti/testmodule/build/android/res/values-v14/themes_base.xml:148: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DialogWhenLarge'.
[exec] [ERROR] /var/folders/x7/h7lgzf1n4nx7fcwr26fdrzxr0000gn/T/mTUYC62ti/testmodule/build/android/res/values-v14/themes_base.xml:159: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionBarWidgetTheme'.
[exec] [ERROR] Error generating R.java from manifest
[exec] [ERROR] Build Failed.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 20 seconds
```

Not only that, but when creating a brand new mobile module project, and building straightaway with ant:

```
cd proj/android && ant install
```

The errors are the same.  I should also point out that I reformatted not too long ago, so I find it unlikely that I have borked my titanium installation already.  Now, from here, I've gotten into the Titanium build scripts to try and figure out what is happening.  First, from the Titanium SDK 3.3.0 release notes:

```
Due to the addition of the appcompat library, there are a number of behavior changes to the application:
...
The target SDK must be set to API level 14 (Android 4.0.x) or higher, or you must have API level 14 or higher installed.
```

Now in the build output for my project:

```
[exec] [TRACE] Writing out AndroidManifest.xml
[exec] [DEBUG] /path/to/my/androidsdk/build-tools/17.0.0/aapt package -m -J /var/folders/x7/h7lgzf1n4nx7fcwr26fdrzxr0000gn/T/mTUYC62ti/testmodule/build/android/gen -M /var/folders/x7/h7lgzf1n4nx7fcwr26fdrzxr0000gn/T/mTUYC62ti/testmodule/build/android/AndroidManifest.xml -S /var/folders/x7/h7lgzf1n4nx7fcwr26fdrzxr0000gn/T/mTUYC62ti/testmodule/build/android/res -I /path/to/my/androidsdk/platforms/android-10/android.jar
```

Note that it's using the tools for android-10 and not android-14+ which is strange considering the relevant bits of my timodule.xml and build.properties:
timodule.xml:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<tool-api-level>19</tool-api-level><!-- deprecated - see below -->
```

build.properties:

```
titanium.platform=/Users/trey/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.3.0.GA/android
android.platform=/Users/trey/sdk/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-19
google.apis=/Users/trey/sdk/android-sdk-macosx/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-19
android.ndk=/Users/trey/sdk/android-ndk-r9d
```

As it turns out, it seems to be only the deprecated element that matters, and not in timodule.xml at all.  Build scripts are found at `$titanium_sdk/$os/$version/android/`
Observation: Setting `MIN_API_LEVEL = 19` (or 14) instead of 10 in builder.py fixes the issue.  So the build script is ignoring my configuration and using the default.  This seems to happen in the **init** method of the builder class:

```
temp_tiapp = TiAppXML(self.project_tiappxml)
if temp_tiapp and temp_tiapp.android:
    if 'tool-api-level' in temp_tiapp.android:
        self.tool_api_level = int(temp_tiapp.android['tool-api-level'])
        tool_api_level_explicit = True
```

This sets the tool_api_level that the build script uses, but in my case it never gets called because there is not tiapp.xml.  So I made a tiapp.xml, and put it in my example project.  It has the same configs as the timodule.xml.  As part of the build process this gets copied along with the rest of the example project into a temp folder that will be used to build and run the project.  `self.project_tiappxml` in the code above is the root of the project.  And there is still no tiapp.xml there, because it was copied to the Resources directory with everything else, so `tool_api_level` always gets set to the default of 10. That is basically as far as I've gotten.

So, again my question: is my configuration wrong, or is this a bug.  It seems to me that if it is a bug, then no one would be able to build android modules, best I can tell.  So if it's my fault, what have I done to cause it, and how can I fix it.

Update:  If you saw my last edit, that was wrong and I'm sorry - my selected SDK for ti was 3.2.3! Fixed that and it creates the new project fine.  It also builds.  However, installing the example project still results in the same error as above:

```
[exec] [ERROR] Error generating R.java from manifest
[exec] [ERROR] Build Failed.
```

I also added a line above the call to aapt, to clarify that these errors occur while trying to write AndroidManifest.xml for the example project.

Answer (score 0):

Its good you are working with 3.3.0, because from this version Android module creation is relatively easy.by viewing your build.properties i think something is missing or you forgot to add completely here it should be something close to :

```
titanium.platform=/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.3.0.GA/android
android.platform=/Users/xxxxxx/Documents/adt-bundle-mac/sdk/platforms/android-16
google.apis=/Users/xxxxxx/Documents/adt-bundle-mac/sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-16
android.ndk=/Users/xxxxxx/Documents/android-ndk
```

but what i would suggest is check the following things as they get missed often:

1. you should have android-ndk installed and in the path
2. you must have gperf installed with your system(for mac comes with xcode command line tools)

Followed by running the following command in your terminal:

```
ti create -p android -t module -d <WORKSPACE_DIR> -n <MODULE_NAME> -u <MODULE_URL> --id <MODULE_ID> 
## Sample Command
ti create -p android -t module -d ~/Documents/Sample_Workspace/ -n calc -u http:// --id org.appcelerator.calc
```

If everything is alright you will have a module in your `Sample_Workspace` folder with name `calc`and the given id.

you can work on it directly by importing it to your eclipse. and once done can build it using `ant` over the directory.

Hope it helps. Check the [module creation guide](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Android_Module_Development_Guide).

Comment: Thanks for you response. I didn't post my entire build.properties. Will post the output of the cli create shortly.  I do have all of the required software installed.  This is an issue with the new AppCompat requirement.